# CSS: small-caps, the first letter is a bit bolder

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is there a way to make the First letter a bit more thinner or [vice verca](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vice+versa)? Please see the image and css provided.

css:

```
table.form td {
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

[image]

As you can see the first letter of each word which is capitalized is a bit more black/bolder

Comment: It is unclear whether you want to make the first letter thinner or bolder. The problem appears to be that you are using `font-variant: small-caps`, which produces “fake small caps”, which are really just reduced-size capitals, hence with smaller stroke width than normal capitals. And the accepted answer deals with other things, so it remains unknown what the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first letter of each word not.

But you can for the first letter in the `td` element using the [`:first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-letter) pseudo selector

For only enlarging the first letter of each word you could use the [`text-transform:capitilize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform)

Demo with both tricks : http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/8KjT5/1

---

Alternatively if using jquery you could use the [`Lettering.js` plugin](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js)

Calling it with

```
$(function(){
    $('table.form td').lettering('words');
});
```

combined with the css

```
table.form td span[class^="word"]{
    display:inline-block;
}
table.form span[class^="word"]:first-letter {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:17px;
}
```

you get the desired result as seen at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/8KjT5/3/

Comment: How does this address the main question, making the first letter thinner?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela "*or vice verca*" and the attached screenshot.. My understanding was that the basic issue was how to target the first letter of each word for special styling..

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a different (more thinner) font and then use the [`:first-letter`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp) CSS3 selector to make the first letter larger instead. There are a number of Open-Type fonts similar to the one you posted.

```
table.form td {
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 15px;
}

    table.form td:first-letter {
            font-size: 18px;
    }
```

Comment: That works for the first letter of the element, not first letter of each word

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way you can do it in css. You'll have to wrap the first letter of each word in an extra element and then style it

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the first letter of each word capitalized, and then `font-variant: small-caps` would give you the result you are after. Luckily, we can do that using CSS too:

```css
{
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

This works on Chrome 73 on MacOS. Didn't test on other browsers.