# How to get the first letter of each word to be a different size and the rest to be the same size

Tags: html, css

How can I make the first letter of each word in a text to be a different size to the rest?

For example I am trying to make the J in jogging to be bigger than ogging and J in jog to be bigger than og. Also everything has to be capital letter.

JOGGING JOG

So far i have

HTML:

```html
<h1>
    JOGGING JOG
</h1>
```

```css
h1{
    font-family: amatic sc,cursive;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 120px;
}
```

I looked up some information but it seems this can only be done in JavaScript. I might be wrong but if possible can this be done with HTML and CSS only? Maybe using different classes to hold info and then positioning the letters?

Comment: Maybe something like this https://jsfiddle.net/aow3qm9s/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: small-caps, the first letter is a bit bolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063913/css-small-caps-the-first-letter-is-a-bit-bolder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy cross browser solution, is this:

```css
h1{
  font-family: amatic sc,cursive;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
}
h1 span { font-size: 40px; }
```

```html
<h1><span>J</span>OGGING <span>J</span>OG</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `font-variant` CSS property with a value of `small-caps`. ("Small caps" is the correct name of the typographical effect you are looking for.)

The CSS designers have already anticipated your requirement, and thoughtfully provided a solution, so all we have to do is specify the single CSS property `font-variant`.

`font-variant` will render lower-case letters as smaller-sized capitals, and upper-case letters as normal size. Therefore, specify the letters you want bigger ("J") as upper case, but the letters you want smaller as lower case ("ogging", "og"):

```
<h1>Jogging Jog</h1>
```

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-variant-caps-prop), `font-variant`

> Enables display of small capitals. Small-caps glyphs typically use the form of uppercase letters but are reduced to the size of lowercase letters.

Example:

[image: Sample output using font-variant: small-caps]

```css
h1 {
  font-family: amatic sc, cursive;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 30px;

  /* MAGIC HERE */
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<h1>Jogging Jog</h1>
```

Comment: Ah sorry i am getting confused. You mean in the html file in h1 i need to put Jogging Job and just link it in the css? If so i hae done this but it has not worked

Comment: What are you confused about? In the example you gave, simply write the content of the `h1` as "Jogging Jog" (instead of "JOGGING JOG"), and add the single `font-variant` property rule to the CSS for `h1`.

Comment: Sorry for some reason it did not work. The answer below did those

Comment: Instead of rewriting your HTML as in that answer, you should just figure out why this is not working for you, especially after @styletron went to trouble of putting up the fiddle. By using `font-variant`, this will just work, for all h1s, everywhere. I guess you would prefer to rewrite the h1s on all your pages using spans for the first letter?

Comment: Using spans he can size the letter exactly as he wanted, but he can't using font-variant.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande You're right. However, note that depending on the font, `small-caps` will actually invoke different glyphs specifically designed based on best typographical practices for use as small caps. Even if that is not the case, the behavior of `font-variant: small-caps` is designed by experts be the most appropriate size, so I wouldn't expect your requirement for modifying the sizes to arise in real life.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**CSS**

```
h1:first-child:first-letter { float: left; color: #903; font-size: 75px; line-height: 60px; padding-top: 4px; padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 3px; font-family: Georgia; }
```

For reference please check [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/drop-caps/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: But this only addresses the first letter of the element, not the first letter of each word as the OP seems to want.

Comment: Ah thanks this works for the first J in jogging but not the last J in jog :(

Comment: you can modify your html like <h1>Jogging</h1><h1>Job</h1>